# Django-Postman disable email notification per user

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out how to enable/disable the email notifications in Django-Postman on a user base. The notification system is already included, I would like to be able to set a field per user containing a boolean wether that user wants to receive Postman notification mails.

I have found the following setting in postman.utils:

```
# to disable email notification to users
DISABLE_USER_EMAILING = getattr(settings, 'POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING', False)
```

But how would I use this?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

That code says that `django-postman` reads a setting (from your `settings.py` file) called `POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING`, and if no value is set, it defaults to `False`.

[The docs](https://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) say:

> POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING
>
> Set it to True if you do not want basic email notification to users. This setting does not apply to visitors (refer to
>   POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS), nor to a notifier application (refer to POSTMAN_NOTIFIER_APP)
>
> Defaults to: False.

However, that turns emailing on and off across the whole system. To disable user emailing on a per-user basis as you request, this code in `postman/utils.py` points to an answer:

```
if notification:
    # the context key 'message' is already used in django-notification/models.py/send_now() (v0.2.0)
    notification.send(users=[user], label=label, extra_context={'pm_message': object, 'pm_action': action})
else:
    if not DISABLE_USER_EMAILING and user.email and user.is_active:
        email('postman/email_user_subject.txt', 'postman/email_user.txt', [user.email], object, action)
```

So a hacky way to make emailing per-user would be to add a field (or function) to your User object and add another check into that line in `postman\utils.py`.

A better way would be to use django-postman's built-in support for a notification framework like [django-notification](https://django-notification.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which allows you to customise messaging (including email) on a per-user basis.